# Constraint not working properly on ios 7 but it is working fine ios 8

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

Here is first screenshot which is working fine on ios 8 without breaking constraint.
[image]

But when I tried to run it on ios 7.1

the result link following screen with breaking some constraint
[image]

breaking constraint result here:

```
 (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7867df70 V:|-(46)-[UILabel:0x7867cde0]   (Names: '|':CustomVIew:0x7867cb00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7867dfd0 V:[UILabel:0x7867cde0]-(77)-[UILabel:0x7867dad0]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x78782e90 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7867cde0.midY == + 117>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x78773a00 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7867dad0.midY == + 195>"
)
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Comment: add the code for your constraints.

Comment: This seems like a correct behaviour, top image is a bigger screen (more height) bottom screen is a smaller screen, it doesn't matter which ios it is. In the bottom screen you don't have so much height so it probably broke constraint between those 2 labels and moved them according to their top/bottom constraints. Could you describe what you want to achieve so that we can help you?

Comment: @haluzak This output for same screen iphone 4s  3.5 inch os is different one iphone 4s simultator os is 7.1 another is 8.4 constraint working fine on 8.4 not 7.1.

Comment: @VinodJadhav Sorry I didn't notice the difference because of the white background, I see now that I have downloaded both images. Can you provide more info? Some sample code or how your constraints are setup.

Comment: @haluzak I have updated my app Screenshot